# _tkinter.TclError: image "score6" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello so I've been trying to solve this problem but cant find anything I tried dictionaries and exec. How can I use string value as a variable name? I have a problem when I define a variable name in a string and try to make a button with the image it shows error - _tkinter.TclError: image "score6" doesn't exist, but if I manually type in the image variable name the error doesn't show.

```
 img = 'score' + str(correct)  #here I make the variable name #the scores can be from 0-9
                 
 self.rez = Button(window, relief="sunken", image=img, bd=0, bg='#cecece',activebackground='#cecece') 
 self.rez.place(x=520, y=330)
```

#this is where images are defined(this is outside the class)

```
score0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/09.png"))
score1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/19.png"))
score2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/29.png"))
score3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/39.png"))
score4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/49.png"))
score5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/59.png"))
```

`so how can I use string value as a variable name?`

Comment: Have you multiple instances of `Tk`?

Comment: @Thingamabobs  I think no

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll probably want to import `Pathlib` to work with the absolute paths to your image files

```
from pathlib import Path
```

Then I think it might make more sense to put your image filenames into a list...

```
image_dir = Path(r'C:\<path>\<to>\scores')  # the folder containing the images
images = [  # list of individual image file names
    "09.png",
    "19.png",
    "29.png",
    "39.png", 
    "49.png", 
    "59.png",
    ...
]  # etc.
```

And then define a function that can handle fetching these images as needed

```
def set_image(correct):  # I assume 'correct' is an integer
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(
        Image.open(
            # open the correct image (-1 to accommodate zero-indexing)
            image_dir.joinpath(images[correct - 1])  
        )
    )
    return img
```

Then you can update your button's image like so, for example:

```
self.rez.configure(image=img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `eval`

```
img = eval('score' + str(correct))
```

but this is dangerous if `correct` is provided by the user. A better approach is to use a  list

```
images = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/09.png")),
          ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/19.png")),
          ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/29.png")),
          ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/39.png")),
          ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/49.png")),
          ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("scores/59.png"))]

img = images[correct]
```